# can't create project in scrapy says dll load failed

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, conda

from cryptography.hazmat.bindings._openssl import ffi, lib
ImportError: DLL load failed: The operating system cannot run %1.

i installed scrapy through conda by

conda install scrapy -c conda-forge

Answer (score 1):

me too i meet this problem under windows 10 , after many search on many websites . i found this solution :
download this : https://github.com/python/cpython-bin-deps/tree/openssl-bin-1.0.2k
zip the file and copy the folder (amd or win ) in your sys path : C:\Windows\SysWOW64
and voila every thing works fine